# Close winforms application with mainform hidden

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to close my winforms application through the Form.Closing event, with a custom message (Do you want to exit yes/no). For this I have edited the onFormClosing event for every form in my c# project. Like so:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

    // Confirm user wants to close
    switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to close?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
    {
    case DialogResult.No:
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }        
}
```

When the user clicks Yes, I want to get the entire application to exit. However, I have a main form which functions as a loginform. When the user logs in, the mainform gets hidden and a different form displays.

So when the user clicks Yes, the entire application does not end, because of that hidden form. How can I make sure that the entire application gets shut down?

I have tried Application.Exit(), this fires the messagebox confirming the shutdown again, because it calls the OnFormClosing event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly handle `Application.Exit` as its own reason:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown
       || e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall) 
       return;
```

This would let you use `Application.Exit()` to shut down correctly in the handler.  Alternatively, you could just close the main (hidden) form directly.

Answer (score 1):

Reeds solution is the best, if you want you could also try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Comment: Well... you might should not kill your own application.

Comment: You can do it, in some cases, but normally Application.Exit is better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a handle to the login form? Just call `loginForm.Close()` and put your confirmation dialog handling only in the real main form. Since the login form is the one you passed to `Application.Run()`, closing it will close the application.